# Grep with Regex: Finding a word followed by a number within certain range

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

This seems like a rather simple request, but I'm finding it rather difficult to work out.

I have a file, "results.json" which looks like this (simplified):

```
{
          "policyId" : "pol1",
          "policyName" : "Security-High",
          "threatLevel" : 7,
          "policyViolationId" : "high",
},
{
          "policyId" : "pol2",
          "policyName" : "Security-Low",
          "threatLevel" : 1,
          "policyViolationId" : "low",
},
{
          "policyId" : "pol3",
          "policyName" : "Security-High",
          "threatLevel" : 10,
          "policyViolationId" : "high",
}
```

I want to scan the file, and then if it finds anything called `"threatLevel" :` followed by 7, 8, 9 or 10, I want the script to report it.

It's been difficult to implement "7-10" within any sort of regex check using grep.

This is what I've tried so far, via a bash shell script :

**Works but looks a bit untidy**

```
if grep -q "threatLevel\" : 7\|threatLevel\" : 8\|threatLevel\" : 9\|threatLevel\" : 10" "$FILE"; then
    echo 'threshold string does exist';
else   
    echo 'threshold string does not exist';
fi

*Output: threshold string does exist*
```

**Works, but would prefer not to use an elif as it's not exactly a different circumstance**

```
if grep -q "threatLevel\" : [7-9]" "$FILE"; then
    echo 'threshold string does exist';
elif grep -q "threatLevel\" : 10" "$FILE"; then
    echo 'threshold string does exist';
else   
    echo 'string does not exist for regex 7-10';
fi

*Output: threshold string does exist*
```

**Doesn't work .. why?**

```
if grep -q "threatLevel\" : ([7-9]|10)" "$FILE"; then
    echo 'threshold string does exist';
else   
    echo 'threshold string does not exist';
fi

*Output: threshold string does not exist*
```

Comment: That's not a valid JSON file (a JSON file can only contain a single top-level document and must not containg trailing commas)

Comment: Your third example needs backslashes before the `(`, `|`, and `)` characters, otherwise they're treated literally (meaning grep is looking for parentheses around a digit 7-9 followed by a pipe followed by a 10 in the JSON file).

Comment: @knittl it's simplified, but i get your point.

Comment: Third example could also work passing `-E` option to grep (extended regexp).

Comment: `[17-9]0?` should match 7,8,9,10 but also 70, 80, 90. Could work if max value is 10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks for single digit numbers from 7 to 9, or a 10.

```
grep '"threatLevel" : \([7-9]\|10\)'
```

Your attempt didn't work because of escaping. Grep uses POSIX Basic Regular Expressions by default, so escaping is required for a lot of control characters.

Comment: Or switch to ERE: `egrep '"threatLevel": ([789]|10)'` or `grep -E '"threatLevel": ([789]|10)'`

Comment: thanks to both your comments, brilliant stuff!

Comment: @knittl is there a difference between saying ([789]|10) and ([7-9]|10)?

Comment: @cien it might be in some locales, but usually they are identical. It was just easier for me to type `789` :)

Comment: thank you! I've noticed that if the threatLevel were "78" or something silly, it is also being matched by this regex.
this isn't a likely scenario by any means, but is there a way to restrict it to only be 7 or only 8 or only 9 or only 10? not just "a number which has that number within it"

Comment: @cien Use `jq` if you are working with JSON. `grep` is destined to fail if your format changes slightly. For the immediate problem: match `([789]|10)`,, i.e. a number followed by a comma (but this will fail if it is the last property in an object – perhaps `([789]|10),?$`, but now the expression is already becoming complicated).

Answer (score 4):

Not a grep solution, but if you have valid JSON (or JSON-nd) input, grep might not be the best solution to begin with. [jq](/questions/tagged/jq) is a command line tool to parse, filter, and transform JSON documents.

Given the following input (sanitized to contain a stream of valid JSON documents):

```
{
          "policyId" : "pol1",
          "policyName" : "Security-High",
          "threatLevel" : 7,
          "policyViolationId" : "high"
}
{
          "policyId" : "pol2",
          "policyName" : "Security-Low",
          "threatLevel" : 1,
          "policyViolationId" : "low"
}
{
          "policyId" : "pol3",
          "policyName" : "Security-High",
          "threatLevel" : 10,
          "policyViolationId" : "high"
}
```

Then using the following jq call gives you all objects with the given threat level:

```
$ jq 'select(.threatLevel | . >= 7 and . <= 10)' results.json
{
  "policyId": "pol1",
  "policyName": "Security-High",
  "threatLevel": 7,
  "policyViolationId": "high"
}
{
  "policyId": "pol3",
  "policyName": "Security-High",
  "threatLevel": 10,
  "policyViolationId": "high"
}
```

If you only want to get the threat level properties/lines, you'd have to use a slightly different filter:

```
$ jq -r '.threatLevel | select(. >= 7 and . <= 10) | "\"threatLevel\": \(.)"' results.json
"threatLevel": 7
"threatLevel": 10
```

Or to only get the levels:

```
$ jq '.threatLevel | select(. >= 7 and . <= 10)' results.json
7
10
```

You are using your `grep` in an if, so you might as well use `jq` to transform your (fixed) JSON document into values `true` or `false` (and set the exit code):

```
if jq -e 'any(.threatLevel | . >= 7 and . <= 10)' >/dev/null; then
  echo 'threat level 7-10 found';
else
  echo 'threat levels not found';
fi
```

Why jq and not grep? Well, jq properly handles inputs such as:

```
"threatLevel"    :     7
```

or

```
"threatLevel":7
```

or even

```
"threatLevel"
:
7
```

Comment: jq will handle that JSON, but it's still not valid for many parsers, which insist upon a single top-level element; leaving the `,`s after the `}`s and adding a pair of `[`s around the whole thing would probably be the most general solution.

Comment: @MarkReed true, I have changed the wording to be a bit less confusing. jq can handle files with multiple JSON documents in them (a stream of JSON documents). But you are absolutely correct that this is not a valid JSON file, as these can only contain a single root element (primitive, array, or object)